# How to find data entered where date end is 30 days after date start?

Tags: sql

I am trying to pull entries in sql after 2020 where the date end is 30 days or less than date start.

I have this so far, and have been trying to find ways to filter out this data but have been unsuccessful.

Thank you in Advance!

```
where (date_exit >= '2020-01-01')
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: @Jarlh im using SQL with Mode